# How to get collection name from get option in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, angular8

I am triying to get table data from mongodb depends on passing collection name.In my angular project i have one servcie. i am passing the collection name by get method but i do not know how to get that collection name inside the gettable data method.

product.component.js:

```
    ngOnInit(){ 
     this.getProductsData('table'); 
    }

    getProductsData(collection){ 
     this.userService.getTableData(collection).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.tableData =  res; 
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);

      }
    );

  }
```

user.service.ts:

```
getTableData(collection){ 
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/getTableData',collection);
}
```

table.controller.js //Nodejs

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const _ = require('lodash');

var userSchemaTable = new mongoose.Schema({
    product_name: {
        type: String
    },
    price: {
        type: String
    },
    catogery: {
        type: String
    }
}, { collection: 'table' });


mongoose.model('table', userSchemaTable);

const Table = mongoose.model('table');

module.exports.getTableData = (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(collection)

    How to get collection name here??????????????????????

  collection.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ss' + err);
            return
        }
        return res.json(docs)
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getTableData` method to like  this,pass an `object` instead

```
getTableData(collection){ 
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/getTableData?collection=${collection}`);
}
```

And then get the collection name here like this

```
module.exports.getTableData = (req, res, next) => {

 let collection=req.query.collection;
    console.log(collection)

  collection.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ss' + err);
            return
        }
        return res.json(docs)
    }) 
}
```

Comment: is it a get route??

Comment: @KavithaK please try now

Comment: I have one more question: How to create collection dynamically?

Comment: check out this answer @KavithaK -https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131015/7849549

Comment: That link not use: I am not able to pass multiple collection..

Comment: Can you answer my new question?

Comment: Shubh ..you there?